# Adding table (bottom left) programatically to (0,0,0) in Autocad 2015

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

This is my program to open an excel table & programmatically create at a mentioned point. When I specify (0,0) it adds top left corner. But I want the bottom left corner. How would be the code ?

This is my program..

```
[CommandMethod("exl")]
static public void TableFromSpreadsheet()
{
    const string dlName = "Excel to Autocad";
    var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    var db = doc.Database;
    var ed = doc.Editor;
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog("Select Excel Spreadsheet to Link", null, "xls; xlsx", "ExcelFileToLink", OpenFileDialog.OpenFileDialogFlags.DoNotTransferRemoteFiles);
    var dr = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (dr != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        return;
    ed.WriteMessage("\nFile selected was \"{0}\". Contains these sheets:", ofd.Filename);
    var sheetNames = GetSheetNames(ofd.Filename);
    if (sheetNames.Count == 0)
    {
        ed.WriteMessage("\nWorkbook doesn't contain any sheets.");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sheetNames.Count; i++)
    {
        var name = sheetNames[i];
        ed.WriteMessage("\n{0} - {1}", i + 1, name);
    }
    var pio = new PromptIntegerOptions("\nSelect a sheet");
    pio.AllowNegative = false;
    pio.AllowZero = false;
    pio.DefaultValue = 1;
    pio.UseDefaultValue = true;
    pio.LowerLimit = 1;
    pio.UpperLimit = sheetNames.Count;
    var pir = ed.GetInteger(pio);
    if (pir.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;
    var ppr = ed.GetPoint("\nEnter table insertion point");
    if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
        return;
    var dlm = db.DataLinkManager;
    var dlId = dlm.GetDataLink(dlName);
    if (dlId != ObjectId.Null)
    {
        dlm.RemoveDataLink(dlId);
    }
    var dl = new DataLink();
    dl.DataAdapterId = "AcExcel";
    dl.Name = dlName;
    dl.Description = "Excel 2 Autocad";
    dl.ConnectionString = ofd.Filename + "!" + sheetNames[pir.Value - 1];
    dl.DataLinkOption = DataLinkOption.PersistCache;
    dl.UpdateOption |= (int)UpdateOption.AllowSourceUpdate;
    dlId = dlm.AddDataLink(dl);
    using (var tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dl, true);
        var bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(db.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
        var tb = new Table();
        tb.TableStyle = db.Tablestyle;
        tb.Position = ppr.Value;
        tb.Cells.SetDataLink(dlId, true);
        tb.GenerateLayout();
        var btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
        btr.AppendEntity(tb);
        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(tb, true);
        tr.Commit();
    }
```

}

Comment: I believe this position if fixed and you would need to recalculate the Position using the BoundingBox after GenerateLayout.

Comment: I would be delighted if you explain me about BoundingBox. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this Extension method (didn't have more time to test it...)

```
/// <summary>
/// Recalculate the position for a bottom left coordinate.
/// Must be called after GenerateLayout().
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tbl">Table object</param>
/// <param name="bottomLeft">Bottom Left desired position</param>
public static void MoveToBottomLeft(this Table tbl, Point3d bottomLeft)
{
  Point3d maxPoint = tbl.Bounds.Value.MaxPoint; // this is the bottom left (min point)
  Point3d topLeft = new Point3d(maxPoint.Y, bottomLeft.Y, bottomLeft.Z); // this should be topLeft
  Point3d newPosition = bottomLeft.TransformBy(Matrix3d.Displacement(bottomLeft.GetVectorTo(newPosition))); // move bottomLeft to newPosition
  tbl.Position = newPosition; // apply the new position
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time !! Once again.